# Unsupervised clustering for Text labelling

Tags: nlp, text-mining, labelling

I have millions semi structured text descriptions of a job requirement.
Which needs to be labelled, such as the number of hours, years of experience required, shifts, certifications, licensure etc., Need to segregate them and put it in a structured format, was wondering if I can use some unsupervised labelling methods.

P.S: Details are not all structured to use regular expressions.

Comment: I think this looks like custom Named Entity Recognition, but it's supervised of course. To the best of my knowledge there's no "unsupervised labelling method" for task-specific entities like this.

Comment: Thank you @Erwan